# In cakephp - can I counterCache related models? eg: User -> Profile

Tags: php, cakephp, counter-cache

I have a field `member_count` on my `countries` table.

`Profile` belongsTo `Country`

```
counterCache => 'member_count',
counterScope => array( 'Profile.country => 'US' )
```

So, when a user runs a save on `$this->User->Profile->save( $this->data)`, i would like to update the `counterCache` in `Country`.

Possible?

Comment: Yes, I did try it many different ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barry its not listed as an option on a hasMany relationship in the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/ar/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together#hasMany-1043)

I suppose you could cache a view with the results of the countries and their number of profiles to save you some performance as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Please have another look [in the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1033/counterCache-Cache-your-count) to make sure, you did everything right.

Your Profile-Model should look like this:

```
function Profile extends AppModel {
    $name = 'Profile';
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Country' => array(
            'counterCache' => 'member_count'
        )
    );
}
```